# mongo db: поиск по нескольким критериям

Tags: mongodb, meteor

работаю с mongodb 3.2
не могу сделать поиск по нескольким полям. например в yii было проще:

```
$command = Yii->createCommand($sql)
if ($one) $command->addCondition($cond1);
if ($two) $command->addCondition($cond2);
$result = $command->queryAll();
```

а в mongodb получается только 1 раз можно задать параметры, и дальше запускается поиск

```
db.coll.find({});
```

хотелось бы вот так:

```
curs = myColl.find();
if(cond1) {
   curs2 = curs.find({cond2})
}
```

то есть, иерархично будем двигаться, по ходу добавляя отсеивая фильтры

P.S:пишу АПИ, почему то $where не пашет у меня..(meteor 1.3,nimble/restivus)

**UPD**

```
{
        "_id" : "u5QYDyrbXn24FYaQD",
        "baseFields" : {
                "carCatId" : "yCHznKsJaMjL3dzTM",
                "carClassId" : "c69tHZHGWyxLDthkL",
                "carClassTplId" : 4,
                "carMarkaId" : "76Xme6nPQyaLQST9g",
                "carGosNomer" : "Z 123",
                "carProductionYear" : "2010",
                "carHourlyPrice" : "5000"
        },
        "extraFields" : {
                "carKubatura" : "2000",
                "carTonna" : "5000"
        }

}
{
        "_id" : "H53hpx6mBPrWPTPCB",
        "baseFields" : {
                "carCatId" : "ye3DNu482L9uGeMqk",
                "carClassId" : "4sf3eXAcqmLe7XysY",
                "carClassTplId" : 3,
                "carMarkaId" : "i3BKrpJf4baLYo8Ky",
                "carGosNomer" : "LLL",
                "carProductionYear" : "2010",
                "carHourlyPrice" : "5000"
        },
        "extraFields" : {
                "carSeats" : "4",
                "carColor" : "1"
        }
```

}

пытаюсь найти так:

```
var cond = {'baseFields':{}};
cond.baseFields.carCatId = 'yCHznKsJaMjL3dzTM';
db.mycoll.find(cond);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii от вас просто скрывал эти детали. На самом деле всё так же, как и в SQL - вам нужно самостоятельно собрать условие поиска (или текст запроса для SQL) и его передать в один-единственный вызов find.

Образно говоря,

```
conditions = {};
if (cond1) {
    conditions['field'] = value; 
    // ну или любую другую допустимую для mongodb структуру запроса
}
myColl.find(conditions);
```

Comment: у меня почему то не ищет как вы предлагали

Comment: ну тогда показывайте, как именно вы пробуете, что при этом в реальности передаётся в find, и, до комплекта, аналогичный запрос в mongo клиенте, который данные-таки возвращает. А, и очень внимательно проверьте на опечатки. Эта хрень под названием mongodb вам нифига не скажет, если вы попытаетесь читать несуществующую базу или коллекцию.

Comment: Ну, а где пруф от штатного клиента mongo, что такой запрос что-то вернёт? Потому что ничего и не вернёт. Mongodb использует нотацию через точку для обращений ко вложенным объектам: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation